# How to prevent iText table PdfPCell spanning across multiple rows from splitting across pages?

Tags: html, itext, page-break

I am using iText (iTextSharp 5.1.1) and I am trying to do some tables.

The first table column spans across several rows. Depending on previous content, the column would sometimes be split on two pages. Sometimes, only one row would remain on the first page, leaving the column not high enough for a label to be displayed.

Is there any way to detect if a column would span across two pages if added to a document, so I can fill in some rows to prevent this behavior.

Or is there a way to tell a cell **not to split** under any circumstances?

Comment: can you post a sample PDF or an image of one so we can see what problem you're having? I created a 2 column `PdfPTable` and added a `PdfPCell` that spans 5 rows. Then I added 5 more `PdfPCells` with long text that caused the table to span to two pages. (Sample PDF below.) The spanned cell's contents appear at the top of the first page which is expected and the second page just has blank space for the first column which is expected. http://chris.vendiadvertising.com/Stackoverflow/6904151-RowSpanning/Output.pdf

Comment: In terms of your example, what I really need is for the 4th row not to break, but instead to be placed in its entirety on another page. Basically that would mean that no cell should be broken across two pages. What I can guarantee (in my scenario) is that the cell will only be a few lines long, so it will definitelly fit on a page (if it was placed at the beginning of the new page).

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention (it may or may not be relevant), the first column (that spans across multiple rows) is rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: I have the same problem with a fairly simple three column table. The first cell is an image which is compressed in size as two text lines out of five are split onto the next page

Comment: With `table.setSplitLate(false);` the rows would be split into two parts. So you'd need to use `table.setSplitLate(true);` to achieve what you are looking for... right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I coded your example with iText 2.1.7 in Java:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setSplitLate(true); // default value
PdfPCell largeCell =
        new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\r\n"
                + "consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur\r\n"
                + "vel nisl quis turpis molestie blandit.\r\n"
                + "Donec a ligula sit amet quam feugiat\r\n"
                + "aliquet in id augue. Etiam placerat\r\n"
                + "massa ac ligula dictum convallis.\r\n"
                + "Mauris in leo quis lorem facilisis\r\n"
                + "tincidunt. Praesent lorem libero,\r\n"
                + "porttitor tincidunt egestas consequat,\r\n"
                + "tempor quis erat. Sed lorem ipsum,\r\n"
                + "posuere a ornare ac, viverra ut diam. In\r\n"
                + "porta ultrices tristique. Nulla non libero\r\n"
                + "a nisi pharetra consequat. Vestibulum\r\n"
                + "nunc urna, lobortis id ultricies vitae,\r\n"
                + "fermentum eu magna. Duis nibh lacus,\r\n"
                + "adipiscing at tempor eget, interdum\r\n" + "quis libero."));

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Long Column"));
cell.setRowspan(5);
table.addCell(cell);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    table.addCell(largeCell);
}
```

And it works quite well as asked by Kornelije... The "wrong" output will only be produced, when I use `table.setSplitLate(false)`, so with the default value of `true` everything is just fine.